# Closing a socket created in a dll

Tags: python, windows, sockets, modbus, libmodbus

I'm creating a modbus slave using the libmodbus.dll in python on Windows OS. I've used ctypes to load the dll and make use of its features. There is a sample code I'm mimicking [here](https://github.com/pjmaker/libmodbus-wee-example/blob/master/slave.c). One of the call's in the dll ends up opening a socket

```
s = modbus_tcp_listen(ctx, 1);
```

At the end of the example it has a line where it close's the socket like so

```
close(s);
```

`close()` is not part of the libmodbus.dll. It's from the library `#include <unistd.h>`. Is there a way to close the socket without having to obtain a dll with the `close()` functionality? If not, how would I obtain access to the `close()` command on a windows platform? From what I know `unistd.h` is for posix.

Comment: if this code works on Windows, then Windows must have a `close` function *somewhere*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `socket.close(fd)` which takes the socket descriptor and closed it.

```
import socket
...
server_socket = mbpi.modbus_tcp_listen(self._ctx, 1)
...
socket.close(server_socket.value) # Need to call attribute value since its a ctypes.c_int
```